# Copying files based on file name in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I want to copy files from one folder to another, but only if the filename begins with the letter 'w'. Below is the script I've come up with so far, but it's not working. There are two loops in the script, because there are files in three folders (i.e. subjects) and each of these folders has four subfolders, which I want to scan through for 'w*'-files. The files should be copied from "folderx" to "folderxnew".

```
for n_subj = 1:3

   cwd_all = { '/data/subject1/';      '/data/subject2';      'data/subject3'; };

   cwd = cwd_all{n_subj};

   dirs{1}='folder1';
   dirs{2}='folder2';
   dirs{3}='folder3';
   dirs{4}='folder4';

   dirt{1}='folder1new';
   dirt{2}='folder2new';
   dirt{3}='folder3new';
   dirt{4}='folder4new';

   for nses=1:4

        dir = dirs{nses};

        files = dir('w*');

        copyfile(files, dirt{nses},'f');

    end

end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For code to be formatted as a code - prepend each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: As it seems you have found the solution, could you explain a little more what you did and post it as an answer? Otherwise the question will remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this loop:

```
for nses=1:4

    files = dir([dirs{nses} '\w*']);

    for i =1:length(files)
        copyfile(files(i).name, dirt{nses},'f'); 
    end

end
```

Comment: It comes up with the same error as before: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Comment: @user2609464 try executing each line at command window, and tell which line throws this error ?

Comment: Sorry, there was no error. The script goes through all the iterations just fine, but no files are copied. "files" seems to be a 0x1 struct array, so I'm guessing that it hasn't actually found any of the w-files?

Comment: Ah got it now, I should've used cd instead of cwd.. Solves the problem. Thank you for all your help :)!

Answer (score 0):

First, try not to define your constants inside the loop (although this has nothing to do with the results).

Second, your original code creates a variable called "dir" out of the i'th iteration of the nses loop.  This will override the "dir" function you want to call next.

Finally, none of the code includes full path naming, which means MATLAB is looking in your current working directory when you call "copyfile(files ...)"  You'll need to pass the proper concatenation of cwd and dirs(nses).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered many situations like this that require specific file copying and renaming tasks.
So I wrote a function "easycopy" (and sister function "easyrename") in matlab to provide a convenient way of copying and renaming files using lists and wildcards.

You can check them out on Matlab File Exchange:

[https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63417-easycopy][1]

[https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63586-easyrename][1]

Here's what it looks like in this situation:

The ? wildcard with "subject" matches directory subjec1,2,3 and "folder?" matches folder1,2,3,4.
Then the destination expression uses "...subject?\folder?new..." to create folders ...subject(1,2,3)\folder(1,2,3,4)new...
The first source "?" matches the first "?" in the destination expression, the second "?" matches the second dest "?" and so forth.
The "w*.txt" matches all the "w" source files and just copies them to the "w*.txt" destination.

```
easycopy('c:\data\subject?\folder?\w*.txt','c:\data\subject?\folder?new\w*.txt')
COPYING FILES .....

Copying c:\data\subject1\folder1\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject1\folder1new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject1\folder2\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject1\folder2new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject1\folder3\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject1\folder3new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject1\folder4\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject1\folder4new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject2\folder1\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject2\folder1new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject2\folder2\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject2\folder2new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject2\folder3\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject2\folder3new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject2\folder4\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject2\folder4new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject3\folder1\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject3\folder1new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject3\folder2\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject3\folder2new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject3\folder3\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject3\folder3new\wicked.txt

Copying c:\data\subject3\folder4\wicked.txt
To c:\data\subject3\folder4new\wicked.txt

DONE !
```